# jquery problem css when drag item from treeview

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a treeview menu where user can drag something and drop on a list (like gmail with labels). Everything works 99%. When the mouse hover an item in the treeview, the background color changed (that's ok for me). When the mouse leave the item, the background is back to white. The problem is when the (jquery) drag begin, the item background is changed and didn't come back to white as normally should (a refresh problem?).

How can I proceed (when drag start?) to arrange this little problem?

I already try:

> $(this).children().css('background-color','#ffffff');

But it is not acceptable because the css is definitively changed (no more hover/leave difference). I need something like a refresh of the item. I see that if I mouse hover the item (after the drag/drop operation) the background is back to white (as it should).

Screenshot 1
[first image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1114048/img1.jpg)

On this first screenshot we see the user mouse over an item in the treeview and so the background color is light blue. No drag drop this time so ok for me.

Screenshot 2
[second image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1114048/img2.png)

On the screenshot 2 the user drag an item and we see the helper dragged. The problem is that the original itm in the treeview is still blue! Annoying...

If the drag'n drop is cancelled or finished and the user mouseover this blue item, it become back to white background but too late...

**I edit my question to respond to Phortuin**

@Phortuin: the mouseenter, mouseleave events are both managed with css as you can see below:

```
.treeview li{ 
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px; 
  list-style: none;  
}

.treeview li a:hover
{    
  background-color: #f3f7fd;
  border-color: #bbd8fb;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;  
}
```

So if I don't know how to proceed.

Another solution will be to manage mouseover/mouseleave events only with jquery as you showed me but maybe there is an easier solution (and keeping my css)?

Comment: Can you post some code? Preferably with a working example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Khez: I added 2 screenshots. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution as below (with keeping my css as is):

```
    $('#treemenu1 ul li a').hover( function(){ 
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f3f7fd');
        $(this).css('border-color', '#bbd8fb');
    });

    $('#treemenu1 ul li a').mouseleave( function(){ 
        $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
        $(this).css('border-color', 'transparent');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably that a mouseLeave event was never triggered (hover is a wrapper for mouseEnter and mouseLeave). A similar construction would be this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank"><img src="/images/stackoverflow.gif" alt="" /></a>
```

With the following jQuery I change the image on hover:

```
$("img").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src").val("/images/stackoverflow-hover.gif");
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("src").val("/images/stackoverflow.gif");
});
```

Now, when I hover over the image and click the link, the site is opened in a new tab or window, and when I switch back to my original site, the image will still have the stackoverflow-hover.gif image because the mouseLeave event was never triggered.

What you need to do is make sure the behaviour you want is actually triggered. You could do this:

```
$("span.item").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("span.item").bind("mouseleave blur mouseout", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

The bind method will allow you to bind several events to the element, all resulting in the same behaviour. Try this out with several events to see the effects. Also, you could learn about triggering events yourself with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ - you could trigger a custom event in the callback of the drag method:

```
$("span.item").drag(function(){
    // do some dragging
}, function() {
    this.trigger("myEvents:draggingIsFinished");
});

$("span.item").bind("myEvents:draggingIsFinished", function(){
   // do stuff after dragging
});
```